# Wordpress if author/writer is call in single.php

Tags: wordpress, if-statement

Is there a way to query content for each writer?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is built in. If you use permalinks, you can use the URL http://hostname.com/author/obama/ for all posts created by user "obama". 
Also take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url

Comment: This is what I was after. Seems overly complicated but works

`<?php
$by_john = false;
if($post->post_author == '10') {
$by_john = true;
}
?>
 <?php if($by_john) { ?>`